# Increasing an number in PowerShell with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, powershell

I have some files that contain strings like

```
#define PROG_HWNR "#37595"
#define C_HWPROG_NR "24499"
#define PROG_HWNR "#39917"
#define C_HWPROG_NR "24901"
#define C_HWPROG_NR "37598"
```

I put them in a file named regex-test (for testing purposes)

What I want to do is increase each number by one. There are other #defines and numbers that must not be increased, I have a list of all variable names that need to be increased.

I already have a PowerShell command like

```
Get-Content regex-test | foreach { [regex]::match($_,'"#?(\d+)"$').groups[1].value }
```

which returns the numbers. They now only need to be replaced with [value] + 1

Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just:

```
$tmp = Get-Content regex-test | foreach { $n = [regex]::match($_,'"#?(\d+)"$').groups[1].value; if ($n) {$_ -replace "$n", ([int32]$n+1)} else {$_}; }
```

Then save the `$tmp`.

Comment: If you invert `([int32]$n+1)` with `(1+$n)` you don't need the cast thanks to the coercing feature of powershell.